# Planetary gear efficiency for a variable load

Tags: gears

I use the Maxon planetary gear #203115 for a project. Here are its characteristics (from the datasheet):

- $n=12:1$
- 3 stages
- $C_\max=7.5 \mathrm{Nm}$
- $\eta_\max=\eta(C_\max)=0.81$

Maxon precises that the efficiency depends on the torque applied but is independent but is unaffected by the motor speed. They give a schematic curve:
[image: efficiency_curve]

If I assume that the losses come only from dry friction, I find:
$$\eta(C)=\frac{C-C_{frict}}{C}$$
$$\eta_\max=\frac{C_\max-C_{frict}}{C_\max} \Rightarrow C_{frict}=C_\max(1-\eta_\max)=1,425 \mathrm{Nm}$$

Unfortunately these equations give an unrealistically low efficiency for low applied torque:
[image]

How can I model the efficiency more precisely ?

Comment: Friction isn't linear the formula $\mu F_n$ is only true for a very small range of approximations. Real friction is way more complicated to cite Wikipedia " It is a rule of thumb describing the approximate outcome of an extremely complicated physical interaction"